# How to define a private class path with PHP Composer?

Tags: php, composer-php

Is it possible to define a separate PSR-0/4 path for classes/interfaces that can only be loaded by the package itself (not other packages that include it)?

The idea being it would stop other packages from mistakenly using classes that should be private to the package.

I realise that they can always include the file manually and the class loader is global. The goal is not to prevent them from using the class, but rather make it clear that they shouldn't be accessing it directly now or if the API of the package changes.

Use case:

Let say there is a `Person` class in the package (already released and used). When a new version of the package arrives we no longer want them to invoke `new Person`, but instead use a `PersonFactory` (as it has to setup some other stuff with the person that the caller does not need to worry about).

Yes, you could document this in the change log. However an IDE and static analysers would not be able to report on this. The bug would only be discovered when the improperly initialised Person is given to a provider and the program crashes or throws an exception at runtime.

---

Based on Alexander's response, this seems the most reasonable:

https://repl.it/repls/GrowlingInconsequentialFanworms

Comment: Why would another package (presuming one on packagist) load your class/package? If its 2 of your packages then just don't do it. Make everything `final` if you dont want it extended. Composer nor php has isolation.

Answer (score 4):

I can't see how this would be possible, because the autoloader loads them into their defined namespaces on their first usage. Once in a namespace, anything can use it by accessing that namespace.

PHP namespace to not have any way of limiting what other namespaces can access them, so your answer is probably no.

What you could do though is put your private classes in a namespace that tells developers they are private:

```
use yourpackage\private\SomeClass;
```

It won't *stop* them, but it could make it clear they should not do that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible. spl_autoload_register() takes only $class as argument. You can't register autoload only for a part of application. Moreover there is no way to know which class invokes or creates object of the other classes. Even if you wrote your own autoloader you won't get all information that you need.

If you look for securing your code look at [PHP extensions](https://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-php-extension-development-via-php-cpp/).

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure if this is what you talking about but the php keywords private and protected should help a bit when the classes and interfaces are in a namespace

Comment: Yes, it would be most ideal to set a namespace level visibility on the constructor, however as far as I'm aware this is not possible in PHP.

Comment: Quite true, Am not sure if this might work but try using singleton pattern and private or protected, its just a suggestion